# nested conditional to check for feature image and custom field?

Tags: conditional-tags

I have this working for the most part, but some of the syntax is wrong someplace because when the post DOESNT have a thumbnail, it still prints that last echo  and closes a div outside of the conditional. Can someone help me get this syntax on this code right? Basically I want:
Check for venue image, if it's there, display it. If there IS a thumbnail image, then check for a custom field, if it's there, display it. If not, do nothing, if no venue image, do nothing.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) 
echo '<div id="venue-single-img">';
{ // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
the_post_thumbnail();
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Venue Image Notation', true) ) {
echo '<span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Venue Image Notation', true) . '</span>'; }
else {}
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
<?php
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    echo '<div id="venue-single-img">';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Venue Image Notation', true) ) {
        echo '<span>' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Venue Image Notation', true) . '</span>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Great to hear! If my answer helped you, please consider marking it as accepted (the check-mark). Thanks!